# Libgdx -stage inside game play screen conflicts with inputprocessor

Tags: user-interface, libgdx

In my LibGdx game,I want to create a pause button inside game screen.For this,I created a stage object like this.

```
Stage stage;
stage = new Stage(game.viewPort);
```

I wanted to include this statement:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

But another statement is already there;

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputmultiplexer);
```

So when I add a pause button,It is showing up but listener for the button seems to be not working.

```
private void drawPauseButton() {

    pauseButton = new ImageButton(new TextureRegionDrawable(pauseTexture),
            new TextureRegionDrawable(pausePressTexture));
    stage.addActor(pauseButton);

    pauseButton.setPosition(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH,30, Align.bottomRight);

    pauseButton.addListener(new ActorGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public void tap(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int count, int button) {
            super.tap(event, x, y, count, button);
            game.setScreen(new PauseScreen(game));

            // dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Input multiplexer code:

```
public class MyInputProcessor  implements InputProcessor,GestureListener {

public static boolean isTouchDown=false;
public static boolean isTouchUp=false;
public static boolean isTap=false;
public static boolean isLongPress=false;
public static boolean isFling=false;
public static boolean isSwipeDown=false;
public static boolean isSwipeUp=false;
public static boolean isSwipeLeft=false;
public static boolean isSwipeRight=false;
public static boolean isKeyDown=false;

public static boolean isZoomed=false;
public static float zoomInitDist=0;
public static float zoomDist=0;


public MyInputProcessor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     System.out.println("My Input Processor Created..");    
}

public InputMultiplexer returnInput() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer();
      GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(this);
      im.addProcessor(gd);
      im.addProcessor(this);

    return im;
}


@Override
public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.isLongPress=true;
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(Math.abs(velocityX)>Math.abs(velocityY)){
        if(velocityX>0){
                this.isSwipeRight=true;
        }else{
            this.isSwipeLeft=true;
        }
    }else{
        if(velocityY>0){
             this.isSwipeDown=true;
        }else{                                  
              this.isSwipeUp=true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.isZoomed=true;
    this.zoomInitDist=initialDistance;
    this.zoomDist=distance;
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void pinchStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.isKeyDown=true;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}



@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

     MyInputProcessor.isTouchDown=true;
     return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

         MyInputProcessor.isTouchUp=true;
        return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Inside gamescreen class' show method:

```
    MyInputProcessor myInputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
    InputMultiplexer im = myInputProcessor.returnInput();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An InputProcessor that delegates to an ordered list of other InputProcessors. Delegation for an event stops if a processor returns true, which indicates that the event was handled.

Stage implements InputProcessor, you can create another implementation and put into Gdx.input

```
Stage stage=new Stage();               // your 1st InputProcessor
InputPorcessor processor=new InputPorcessor();      //2nd  InputProcessor
...                                                 // may be 3rd  

InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer=new InputMultiplexer();
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(processor);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```

**EDIT**

Add your stage into your multiplexer and return in this way :

```
public InputMultiplexer returnInput(Stage stage) {

     InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer();
     GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(this);
     im.addProcessor(stage);
     im.addProcessor(gd);
     im.addProcessor(this);

     return im;
}
```

Set return value:

```
MyInputProcessor myInputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
InputMultiplexer im = myInputProcessor.returnInput(stage);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);
```

Comment: I added the code for my inputMultiplexer also.Plz check.

Comment: why you want to use Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); by this statement only one InputProcessor(Stage) assign to Gdx.input

Comment: if I am not using that statement,Listener defined for the button is not working.It is just showing the button image only.I need both.stage for pause button and inputmultiplexer for game play.Dont know how to use both together.Thats what the problem

Comment: @AbhishekAryan, when the touchDown returns true, this does not stop the propagation, it registers the object so that the touchUp method is called. To stop the propagation, the Event.setBubbles(false) needs to be called (from within the touchDown method).

Comment: @Niranjana you're not adding stage processor into multiplexer. MyInputProcessor extends InputAdapter implements InputProcessor ? what it make sence. ? **InputAdapter is Adapter class of InputProcessor**

Comment: Sorry,It was a mistake happend while copying the code.I edited the code.

Comment: @Niranjana change your **returnInput** method, check updated answer

Comment: @AbhishekAryan.May be you can help me in this question also.Please check.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578795/drawing-pause-screen-as-a-layer-over-the-play-screen-libgdx]