# Creating Pause Screen Menu inside play screen in LibGdx?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, libgdx

Inside my gameplay screen I want to create a Pause Screen Menu which I can select the Retry button or Back to main screen if I click the pause button.I already draw the pause button inside my class.My problem is how can I draw the pause menu screen?

Here is my code

```
    //pause
    pause = new Texture("pause.png");
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(pause);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    pause_btnDialog = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    pause_btnDialog.setPosition(580,1150);

    stage.addActor(pause_btnDialog); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    pause_btnDialog.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            System.out.println("Pause Button Pressed");
            //Show Pause Screen menu
            //game.setScreen(new PauseGameday1(game));

        }
    });
    stage.addActor(pause_btnDialog);
```

GameScreen

```
public class IngamedayOne implements Screen ,InputProcessor {

final MyGdxGame game;
// Constant rows and columns of the sprite sheet
private static final int FRAME_COLS = 5, FRAME_ROWS = 1;
private boolean peripheralAvailable;
private static final float ACCELERATION     = 20f;

// Objects used
Animation<TextureRegion> walkAnimation; // Must declare frame type (TextureRegion)
Texture cat ,left_paw,right_paw,progressbar_background,progressbar_knob,pause,meter;
Texture carpet,desk,plants,square_carpet,shoes;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Sprite sprite;
private  Texture Background;
ImageButton left_paw_btn,right_paw_btn,pause_btnDialog;
Viewport viewport;
private Stage stage;
// A variable for tracking elapsed time for the animation
float stateTime;
private TextureRegion myTextureRegion;
private TextureRegionDrawable myTexRegionDrawable;

private boolean isPause;
private Group pauseGroup;

//Screen Size
OrthographicCamera camera;
float catSpeed = 50.0f; // 10 pixels per second.
float catX;
float catY;
public boolean paused = false;

public IngamedayOne(final MyGdxGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
    Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
    Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
    stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport( 720, 1280));
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 720, 1280);
    camera.translate( 1280/2, 720/2 );
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

    viewport = new StretchViewport(720, 1280);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    // Load the sprite sheet as a texture
    cat = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cat.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(cat);
    catX=300;
    catY=0;

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor( this);
    peripheralAvailable = Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer);
    int orientation = Gdx.input.getRotation();
    Input.Orientation nativeOrientation = Gdx.input.getNativeOrientation();

    viewport = new StretchViewport(720, 1280);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    // Progressbar
    progressbar_background = new Texture("progression_map.png");
    progressbar_knob = new Texture("cat_head.png");

    //pause
    pause = new Texture("pause.png");
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(pause);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    pause_btnDialog = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    pause_btnDialog.setPosition(580,1150);

    stage.addActor(pause_btnDialog); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    pause_btnDialog.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            System.out.println("Pause Button Pressed");
            //Show Pause Screen menu
            game.setScreen(new PauseGameday1(game));

            pause();
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(pause_btnDialog);

    meter = new Texture("meter.png");
    //background
    Background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("floor.png")); //File from assets folder
    // Use the split utility method to create a 2D array of TextureRegions. This is
    // possible because this sprite sheet contains frames of equal size and they are
    // all aligned.
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(cat, cat.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS, cat.getHeight()/ FRAME_ROWS);
    // Place the regions into a 1D array in the correct order, starting from the top
    // left, going across first. The Animation constructor requires a 1D array.
    TextureRegion[] walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Initialize the Animation with the frame interval and array of frames
    walkAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.200f, walkFrames);
    // Instantiate a SpriteBatch for drawing and reset the elapsed animation
    // time to 0
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    stateTime = 0f;

    //left_control
    left_paw = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("left_paw.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(left_paw);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    left_paw_btn = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    left_paw_btn.setPosition(10,25);

    stage.addActor(left_paw_btn); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    left_paw_btn.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Left Button Pressed");
            //Start Animation


        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(left_paw_btn);

    //right_control
    right_paw = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right_paw.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(right_paw);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    right_paw_btn = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    right_paw_btn.setPosition(517,25);

    stage.addActor(right_paw_btn); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    right_paw_btn.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Right Button Pressed");
            //Start Animation
            stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time
            camera.update();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(right_paw_btn);

}

public enum State
{
    PAUSE,
    RUN,
    RESUME,
    STOPPED
}

private State state = State.RUN;

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // clear previous frame
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time
    camera.update();
    spriteBatch.begin();
    TextureRegion currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    spriteBatch.draw(Background,0,0);

    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame,catX,catY); // Draw current frame at (50, 50)

    spriteBatch.draw(meter,190,990);
    spriteBatch.draw(progressbar_background,20,1170);
    spriteBatch.draw(progressbar_knob,18,1170);

    //Moving player on desktop
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
        catX -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
        catX += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
        catY += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN))
        catY -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;

    //Mobile acceleration
    if (Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer))
    {
        catX -= Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
        catY += Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
    }
    if(catY<0) {
        catY =0;
    }
    if(catY>  Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-100) {
        catY =Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-100;
    }
    if(catX<0){
        catX =0;
    }
    if(catX> Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-250) {
        catX =Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-250;
    }

    switch (state)
    {
        case RUN:
            //do suff here
            break;
        case PAUSE:
            break;
        case RESUME:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    spriteBatch.end();
    stage.act(); //acting a stage to calculate positions of actors etc
    stage.draw(); //drawing it to render all
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);

}
@Override
public void pause() {
    this.state = State.PAUSE;
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    this.state = State.RESUME;
}
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() { // SpriteBatches and Textures must always be disposed
    spriteBatch.dispose();
    cat.dispose();
    left_paw.dispose();
    right_paw.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
    Background.dispose();
    progressbar_background.dispose();
    progressbar_knob.dispose();
}
}
```

Pause Menu

```
public class PauseGameday1 implements Screen {
final MyGdxGame game;
private Texture Background,pauseImg;
private Stage stage;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
OrthographicCamera camera;
private static final int WIDTH= 720;
private static final int HEIGHT= 1280;
private TextureRegion myTextureRegion;
private TextureRegionDrawable myTexRegionDrawable;
Viewport viewport;

public PauseGameday1( MyGdxGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport( 720, 1280));
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 720, 1280);
    camera.translate( 1280/2, 720/2 );
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

    viewport = new StretchViewport(720, 1280);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("backgroundimage.png")); //background image
    pauseImg = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pausemenu/pause_text.png"));

}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen
    camera.update();
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    spriteBatch.draw(Background,0,0);
    spriteBatch.draw(pauseImg,230,900);

    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); //Perform ui logic
    spriteBatch.end();
    stage.getViewport().apply();
    stage.draw(); //Draw the ui
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}
}
```

Can anyone correct my codes?

Comment: I recommend using two Stage, one for the HUD and one for the gameplay to apply the solution to your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing pause Screen as a layer over the play screen-LibGdx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578795/drawing-pause-screen-as-a-layer-over-the-play-screen-libgdx)

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I try it already but it doesn't work.I got error in pauseGroup =  new Group ; Image semiTransparentBG= ......
   // setSize(Size of screen) and make it semi transparent.
   pauseGroup.addActor(semiTransparentBG);

Comment: And how can I make a pause group?

Comment: Could you post what makes it an error?

Comment: @zarawayun Are you using scene2d for your playpage or you can say for GameScreen ?

Comment: yes sir @AbhishekAryan I edit my question I add gamescreen class..How could i do it? I also create another class for pausemenu. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only declared pauseGroup but never used in your game, Call `pause()` method from pause_button. It will create pauseGroup for you and add to your Stage. In `pause()` method, create Actor(UI) and add to pauseGroup. You can't use multiple screen at a time with your `Game` class because `Game` having reference of single Screen.

```
pause_btnDialog.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) { 
            pause();
        }
});


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // clear previous frame
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen

    camera.update();
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    if(this.state==State.RESUME)
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time
    TextureRegion currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);

    spriteBatch.draw(Background,0,0);
    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame,catX,catY); // Draw current frame at (50, 50)

    spriteBatch.draw(meter,190,990);
    spriteBatch.draw(progressbar_background,20,1170);
    spriteBatch.draw(progressbar_knob,18,1170);
     if(this.state==State.RESUME){
    //Moving player on desktop
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
        catX -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
        catX += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
        catY += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN))
        catY -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;

    //Mobile acceleration
    if (Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer))
    {
        catX -= Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
        catY += Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
    }
    if(catY<0) {
        catY =0;
    }
    if(catY>  Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-100) {
        catY =Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-100;
    }
    if(catX<0){
        catX =0;
    }
    if(catX> Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-250) {
        catX =Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-250;
    }
    }
    switch (state)
    {
        case RUN:
            //do suff here
            break;
        case PAUSE:
            break;
        case RESUME:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    spriteBatch.end();
    stage.act(); //acting a stage to calculate positions of actors etc
    stage.draw(); //drawing it to render all
}

public void pause(){

   this.state = State.PAUSE;
   pauseGroup = new Group;
   Image semiTransparentBG= ......
   // setSize(Size of screen) and make it semi transparent.
   pauseGroup.addActor(semiTransparentBG);

  //crate all other pause UI buttons with listener and add to pauseGroup

  stage.addActor(pauseGroup);

 }

 public void resume() {

   if(this.state = State.PAUSE){
      this.state = State.RESUME;
      pauseGroup.remove();
   }  
 }
```

Comment: Thank You Sir . Should I load image on  `Image semiTransparentBG= ......` ? I'm getting error in that part.

Comment: Image semiTransparentBG=new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("backgroundimage.png")));

Comment: semiTransparentBG is only one of the Actor, create number of Actor as your requirement and add to bgGroup, don't forget to setSize and position of Actor as your requirement

Comment: Make background Image of pauseGroup semitransparent, Color color=semiTransparentBG.getColor(); semiTransparentBG.setColor(new Color(color.r,color.g,color.b,.5f));

Comment: Thank You So Much! Sir  you Solve my Problem  ^_^  I can create now the UI for  pause menu buttons resumes and exit.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Keep it up :)